# R2 Arduino Uno and an R3 Ethernet Shield mismatch

Tags: arduino

I bought an R3 Ethernet shield for my R2 Arduino Uno, but I noticed that it has a few more pins than my R2 Uno has sockets. Do I need to buy a different shield?

[Arduino UNO](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno/)

[Arduino Ethernet Shield](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoEthernetShield)

Comment: Post links to devices and we'll be able to comment.

Comment: It's probably cheaper to buy a new r 3 arduino. The shields I've seen are more expensive than the arduino itself.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. The links are [link](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno/) and [link](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoEthernetShield). Unfortunately, I think that @SimpleCoder might be right. Thank you guys for your time!

Comment: @jippie, that is terrific explanation. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I take a look at [the schematic for R3](http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/Arduino_Uno_Rev3-schematic.pdf),

[image: Partial shematic Uno R3]

it appears that the extra pins at the top left:

[image: Arduino UNO R3]
[image: Arduino Ethernet Shield]

carry the same signal as pin A4 (AD4/SDA) and pin A5 (AD5/SCL).

The extra two pins at the bottom left are respectively unused and attached to +5V according to the same schematic diagram. Unsure why the printing `IOREF` on the PCB gives other impression.

[image: Power connector UNO R3]

As a solution, you should be able to simply wire the top left two connections to the bottom right ones (A4 and A5).

A multimeter should be able to confirm my theory. The new connections on R3 have probably been introduced to allow for smaller shields still using power supply and I2C bus.

As a reference the R2 looks like this:

[image: Arduino Uno R2]